# Solving circular reference

Tags: java, json, spring, eclipselink, circular-reference

I have two classes

class A has

```
private B messageOwner;
```

class B has

```
@JsonIgnore
private List<A> messages = new ArrayList<>();
```

now when i want to send class A as json i want it to contain also informations about class B ( without list )

yet using this it omites class B completely. I tried using @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference but the result was the same.

What is the right way to solve this circular reference?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem with circular references unless you are saying it works without the messages list.  What is the value of the messageOwner relationship, and how have you read in A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Transient
private B messageOwner;
```

This does for the JSON serialization what the `transient` type modifier does for the normal serialization. If the JSON library supports it.

Of course the `messageOwner` will be null after deserialisation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that those classes are entity classes

Comment: Then I dare not suggest something. One tip: for ease of understanding your question, add what kind of JSON text you want. At least _I_ was reading it too fast.